# Conditionally stop interactive and non-interactive ssh login and give error message

Tags: 20.04, ssh, sftp, pam

I want to prevent **interactive** and **non-interactive** ssh login based on a conditional logic. I need to test the username and give an error message.

People using sftp (non-interactive ssh) should also be subject to the luckness test.

How would I implement that? I have full control of the system.

I tried to use sshd ForceCommand, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33714333/746461 it does not work for notty.

I'm not familiar with PAM and I doubt if PAM can output custom error message in case the login is interactive.

https://linuxhint.com/understanding_bash_shell_configuration_startup/ says non-interactive login shell with `--noprofile` option can bypass all bash config files. That's why I can't write my logic there.

Comment: I would recommend a slightly different approach and put users into a group, then using sshd_config's Match Group directive to force a /bin/false type command.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Can you comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33714333/746461 ? I thought it's saying ForceCommand does not work for notty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out. I can implement a PAM module to do that.

Save the following to, say, file `/root/checkConnections`.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

limit=$1
c=$(pgrep -xcu $PAM_USER sshd)
if [[ $c -ge "$limit" ]]; then 
    echo "Max $limit ssh connections allowed, but you have $c."
    exit 1
fi
```

Then in /etc/pam.d/sshd, add

```
session required pam_exec.so stdout /root/checkConnections 5
```

`pam_exec.so` executes the shell script, `stdout` outputs messages to user terimal.

When the condition fails, the effect is like this.

```
$ ssh localhost
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-74-generic x86_64)

94 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

Max 5 ssh connections allowed, but you have 5.
/root/checkConnections failed: exit code 1
Last login: Thu Jun 24 12:19:27 2021 from 172.18.33.67
Connection to localhost closed.
```